# Next key in C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, enumerator

How to get an `Enumerator` to an item in a -Sorted- dictionary using key?

**Note:**`GetEnumerator()` gets an `Enumerator` to first element..

But I need to get an `Enumerator` to the element with a given key in order to gain access to next elements using `MoveNext()` for example...

**Edit:** Or a way to access next elements...

**Edit:** I prefer a const time method...

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

```
var enumerator = dictionary.Keys.SkipWhile(k => k != myKey)
```

Where myKey is the key you're looking for. And you can use the OrderBy extension method if you want to have the keys sorted.

**Edit**: You can't do it in constant with Dictionary/SortedDictionary. Why not implement your own binary search tree (like SortedDictionary is) and you will have O(log n) time lookup and O(1) time `.next()`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is useful to somebody:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
public string myCurrentKey = "some key 5";
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    myDictionary.Add(string.Format("some key {0}", i), i);
}

private void MoveIndex(int dir) { // param "dir" can be 1 or -1 to move index forward or backward
    List<string> keys = new List<string>(myDictionary.Keys);
    int newIndex = keys.IndexOf(myCurrentKey) - dir;
    if (newIndex < 0) {
        newIndex = myDictionary.Count - 1;
    } else if (newIndex > myDictionary.Count - 1) {
        newIndex = 0;
    }

    myCurrentKey = keys[newIndex];
}

Debug.Log(string.Format("Current value: {0}", myDictionary[myCurrentKey])); // prints 5
MoveIndex(1);
Debug.Log(string.Format("Current value: {0}", myDictionary[myCurrentKey])); // prints 6
MoveIndex(-1);
MoveIndex(-1);
Debug.Log(string.Format("Current value: {0}", myDictionary[myCurrentKey])); // prints 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eayzh46.aspx). 
You can accomplish that having possibility of accessing by index, so you can use [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) instead of Dictionary. Also you can have a look at [SkipWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075.aspx).

Although you can have some workaround like this :

```
Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> pair in dictionary)
{ 
   // you can check the key you need and assume that the next one will be what you need.
}
```

But of course this is not the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Framework >=3.5 installed use [SkipWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075.aspx) Janus Tondering and LukeH suggested. 
For lower framework versions you have to do it for yourself(f.e. fill a second dictionary with the keyvaluepairs from your key to the end).

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = yourDictionary.SkipWhile(kvp => kvp.Key != keyToFind);
foreach (var result in query)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to use a `SortedList` and then add an extension method to it that returns an `IEnumerable` whose elements are greater than or equal to the given key. The complexity of the `GetElementsGreaterThanOrEqual` method below is O(log(n)) to get the first element and then each iteration after that is O(1).

```
public static class SortedListExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetElementsGreaterThanOrEqual<TKey, TValue>(this SortedList<TKey, TValue> instance, TKey target) where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
    {
        int index = instance.BinarySearch(target);
        if (index < 0)
        {
            index = ~index;
        }
        for (int i = index; i < instance.Count; i++)
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(instance.Keys[i], instance.Values[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int BinarySearch<TKey, TValue>(this SortedList<TKey, TValue> instance, TKey target) where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
    {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = instance.Count - 1;
        while (lo <= hi)
        {
            int index = lo + ((hi - lo) >> 1);
            int compare = instance.Keys[index].CompareTo(target);
            if (compare == 0)
            {
                return index;
            }
            else
            {
                if (compare < 0)
                {
                    lo = index + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    hi = index - 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return ~lo;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this method be used/called?